# MySQL - Use table with previous states to show status at that time

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database that has a `member` table where there are multiple membership levels (e.g., Basic, Premium) of which a member can have one, and the membership level can change over time. I am working on constructing a query to give a count of the members of each type at any time, so the membership type of each member may be different than it is currently. To do this, I have a few additional tables.

- `types` - Gives id associated with each membership type and its string
- `timeunits` - Gives id associated with each time unit and its string
- `oldtypes` - Gives the old membership type for a member and the time at which it was changed from that type

I know if I want to get a count of the members of each type currently, I can use:

```
SELECT types.type_desc, COUNT(*) FROM member INNER JOIN types ON member.type = types.type_id GROUP BY types.type_id;
```

What I'm not sure about is how to get the appropriate values from the `oldtypes` table given a time unit and use those with the `member` table to get a snapshot of the members and their memberships at any time. So if I were to get the memberships at `timeunit = 2`, I would see as a result:

```
| member_id |    name | type |
|-----------|---------|------|
|         1 |   Alice |    1 |
|         2 |     Bob |    2 |
|         3 | Charlie |    1 |
|         4 |   Daisy |    2 |
|         5 |    Evan |    1 |
|         6 |   Frank |    1 |
|         7 |  Gloria |    2 |
|         8 |   Henry |    2 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/925c4)

EDIT: The `oldtypes` table is constructed such that it gives the membership a member had prior to the listed time, at which point it was changed. So a row reading `4,1,2` indicates that member 4 changed from membership 1 at time 2.

Comment: So you want a `count` or actually the type? What actually is this meant to represent? I'm having a little trouble understanding your last paragraph. Are you trying to show what different types members have had, or almost like a snapshot in time of what members had at a certain timeunit? Timeunit = 2 doesnt have an entry for all members so that is throwing me off a bit in your fiddle.

Comment: Let's say actually the type. If I can generate that, generating the count is easy. It's a snapshot of the memberships at a given time. So the way the `oldtypes` table is set up, which may not be the most efficient way, is that the member changed their membership from some membership at a given time (e.g., the first row says that member 2 changed from membership 1 at time 1).

Comment: So is this what you want? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/925c4/22

Comment: Not quite. The table in my original post is what should be generated when querying the state at timeunit = 2. They changed from the type listed in `oldtypes` at the timeunit listed to either the current one or one that they changed from later.

Comment: OK so if the user doesn't exist in the oldtypes, then they have not yet changed type yet so we take the type from the `member` table?

Comment: Right. Unless they then changed later (e.g., Daisy, who changes from membership 1 to 2 at timeunit 2 and from membership 2 to 4 at timeunit 5). It's also possible that the `oldtypes` table is poorly constructed for what I'm trying to do, in which case changing it might be the best thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99351/discussion-between-lock-and-aliden).